react-simple-keyboard styling
I'm using the react-simple-keyboard library to create a virtual keyboard in my React application. However, I'm having trouble vertically stretching the buttons to fill the entire height of their container
I tryed various CSS adjustments, the buttons do not expand as desired
import React from 'react';
import Keyboard from 'react-simple-keyboard';
import 'react-simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css';
import './main.css';

function App() {
  const handleKeyboardChange = (input) => {
    console.log("Input changed", input);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="keyboardContainer">
        <Keyboard 
          onChange={handleKeyboardChange}
          layout={{ /* Your layout */ }}
          display={{ /* Your display options */ }}
          theme={"hg-theme-default"}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

.keyboardContainer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.react-simple-keyboard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.react-simple-keyboard .hg-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 25%;
}

.react-simple-keyboard .hg-button {
  color: #ff6347;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}


Your code example appears to be incomplete, it throws some errors. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, and clarify in better detail what the specific issue or problem is. Sounds like you have a layout problem, but it's unclear what the current UI you see looks like, or what you are expecting the result to be.
